# How to cut the string?

Tags: javascript

if I have a string e.g. `var myStr="AAAAAAA BBBBB CCCCC DDDDD..."`, this string can have various length contain words with spaces.

I would like to have a function which will sperate the string into an array, that's the string will be cut to segements as elements in the array,
where each element of the array contain the words from the string with total length(including space between words) less tha 10 characters long.

(Each element of array always contain complete words & space between words, not cut word from the middle)

I tried:

```
var words=myStr.split(' ');
```

then.... what is the efficient way to implement?

Comment: Do you mean that longer words will be sliced up, or excluded from the final array?

Comment: Yes, longer words will be sliced up, but always separate by space between words, total length of each element in the array should not larger than 10 characters long.

Comment: split is the correct method to achieve what you want - what is going wrong?

Comment: it would be best if you show us the expected output, like `['AAAAAAA ', 'BBBBB CCCCC ' ...]`. Its hard to understand otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var words = "AAAAAAA BBBBB  CCCCC   DDDDD\tEEEE \t FFFF".split(/\s+/);
```

Once you have the words, you can iterate over words and push each word into a new array as follows:

## EDIT #2

```js
var words = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vulputate, velit et luctus tristique, libero quam ornare ligula, sagittis consequat massa tellus vel nulla.".split(
  /\s+/
);
var output = [words[0]];
for (var i = 1; i < words.length; i++) {
  var word = words[i];
  var prev = output.pop();
  if ((prev + " " + word).length <= 10) {
    output.push(prev + " " + word);
  } else {
    output.push(prev);
    output.push(word);
  }
}
console.log(output);
// ["Lorem", "ipsum", "dolor sit", "amet,", "consectetur", "adipiscing", "elit. Sed", "vulputate,", "velit et", "luctus", "tristique,", "libero", "quam", "ornare", "ligula,", "sagittis", "consequat", "massa", "tellus vel", "nulla."]
```

Comment: @metaforce: Yes it does: [split on MDC docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
var words = myStr.replace(/(\s)/g, ' ').split(' ');
```

(from head, not tested)

Comment: No, this does not meet my requirement, for example, if myStr='AAA BB', your function will give the result ["AAA", "BB"], but for this case, the result should be ["AAA BB"], because the totoal length is less than 10 characters long

Comment: try this regex pattern: /(\s){10}/g

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
var myStr = 'xxx yy wwwwww vvvv bbbbbbbbb cccccccccc a ddddddddddd eee';
var myArray = myStr.match(/.{1,10}(\s|$)|\S{1,10}(?!\s)/g);
for (var i in myArray) myArray[i] = myArray[i].replace(/\s+$/, '');
// myArray => [ 'xxx yy', 'wwwwww', 'vvvv', 'bbbbbbbbb', 'cccccccccc', 'a', 'dddddddddd', 'd eee' ]
```

*Edit 2011-05-31: reflects clarified requirements*

Comment: Also note: I think there was confusion in the question about "including the space" in the ten-char limit.  If so, a simpler regexp would be `\S{1,10}`, which will match any sequence of up to ten non-space characters.

Comment: The OP wants `"AAA BB"` to be split as `["AAA BB"]` but `"AAAAAA BBBB"` as `["AAAAAA", "BBBB"]` since `AAAAAA BBBB` is 11 chars.